# prove that for any pair of natural, there is a power of 2 that separates the pair of natural

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, equivalence-relations

i need to prove that:

$$ \forall i,j  \in  \{1, \_ ,N \} \subset \mathbb{N} \  \exists   k \in \mathbb{N} / (r_{2^k}(i) \leq 2^{k-1} \wedge r_{2^k}(j) > 2^{k-1})\vee (r_{2^k}(i) > 2^{k-1} \wedge r_{2^k}(j) \leq 2^{k-1})$$

i thought that the easy way was just to try it just using induction.
But i couldn't prove the "if p(n) then p(n+1)" just adding the value N+1 to the set,
so i thoguht that maybe i could calculate that $$ k \in \mathbb{N} $$ 
so i thought that maybe i could take $$ k \in \mathbb{N}/ j-i <2^k$$
as the solution, im not 100% sure if that's the answer but anyway i could't prove it either.

Could you help me to prove one of those(or maybe both?)
(and sorry for my bad spelling, english isn't my first language)
EDIT: that $$ k \in \mathbb{N}/ j-i <2^k$$ should be the lower k

Comment: What is $r_k(j)$?

Comment: the rest of dividing j by k. 
$$j = q*k + r_k(j)$$

Comment: Write the two numbers $i$ and $j$ in binary. Look at the first place from the right where they differ. The problem will be easier if "mathematical" notation is dropped.

Comment: thanks :D  that helped a lot